# cannot assign element of array to value in java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a problem when assign value of element of array to double value.

if with this code, i get value of point_check is [8226.3447987]

```
double[] point_check = new double[1];
point_check = dt.get((int)cY,(int) cX);
Log.i("bbb_1", Arrays.toString(point_check));
```

But when i assign it to 1 value double. it not run and say app stoped (i write code in android studio)

```
double[] point_check = new double[1];
point_check = dt.get((int)cY,(int) cX);
Log.i("bbb_1", Arrays.toString(point_check));
double point_check_1 =  point_check[0];
Log.i("bbb",String.valueOf(point_check_1));
```

What problem with it and how can i fix it

Comment: what is the `error` in `LogCat` ?

Comment: What does and what should the method dt.get(int, int) return? Is it double, or double[]?

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code, you need to make this code:

```
point_check = dt.get((int)cY, (int) cX);
```

to be:

```
point_check[0] = dt.get((int)cY, (int) cX);
```

You were setting the array equal to an object, rather than adding a double to the array.

Comment: Not necessarily. Method dt.get can return an array of doubles. In that case it would be OK. What he needs to do is to check the return value of the method dt.get(int, int) if it is what he expects.

Comment: @WrongRhyme Ya, in that case we can't help him because he hasn't put the error or the dt.get(int, int) method.

Comment: dt is a matrix and method dt.get return double[]  i was try to use your way but it not accept, i think problem is not here, i can get and see value of point_check. But problem is when i assign it to double point_check_1, my app exit and say "sorry, app has stppod"

Comment: @Bruce Can you edit your question to add the full dt.get method?

Comment: No, I mean copy+paste the dt.get method, like the code and put it here. I need to see the dt.get method code.